# How to debug custom language in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I developped a java web application that, amoung other things, interprets a custom language. I've added basic DAP support to that java web application in the hope to debug that custom language via a DAP-compatible debugging UI like VS Code.

Now I'm looking how to make VS Code debugger UI communicate with my remote DAP adapter. Unfortunately I couldn't find any way to perform that natively with VS Code. It seems that VS Code requires plugin for that. Am I wrong ?

So I started playing with mock debug plugin and I found I can make it communicate with my DAP adpater on a network port simply by adding a `"debugServer": 8000` (for port 8000) in `launch.json` config of `mock` extension. My web application receives commands (initialize, launch, setBreakpoints, configurationDone, etc.) and responds to them successfully

But VS Code UI still doesn't consider my custom language as debuggable : for instance, the UI does not offer option to place breakpoint in code.

Am I forced to create a custom plugin for debugging my custom language ? As I understood, the goal of DAP is to be agnostic and simplify the debugging of custom languages. Imho forcing developpers to create a custom plugin is opposite to that idea.